# How to add Programs in "Ease of access "?

Tags: windows-7, ease-of-access

It was possible to add programs using Registry there in Windows XP. But for security reasons It's not possible to add from Registry to Ease of access.So, Is there any methods to add programs in `Ease of access` Windows 7?

Comment: What do you mean by *add to Ease of Access*? Do you mean in the `Ease of Access` folder in the Start menu? If so, then you should be able to simply drag-and-drop some shortcuts in there. If you mean in the Control Panel applet, then I highly doubt it is possible without hacking Windows since they completely changed how the Control Panel works in Vista+.

Comment: @synetech Yes I want to add program to the Ease of access menu (when we press WinKey + U).